# Are questions about drinking establishments to be considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are drinking establishments, like pubs, taverns, brewpubs, garden pubs and so on, to be considered on-topic with the expansion of this site?

For example: I am thinking of places where microbreweries have a pub on their premises and are offering some unique beverages to drink!

Comment: Do you have example questions to consider?   It could depend greatly on the kind of questions, I think.